# Tabbar more view controller iPhone

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, tabbar

I would like to know if there is a way to ensure that every time user presses on the "More" button in tabbar, he or she will be presented with list of views that are in there, not to show current view in which user is in. What I would like to get is always have the list of views on every time user press the "More" button.

Comment: I have tried to edit your post to be clearer, but as I am not an iPhone programmer, I might not have changed it to say what you actually meant. If that's the case, please roll back my edits. You can do this by clicking on the link showing the date I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but there may be some edge cases that I didn't consider.

In the appDelegate:

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

...

-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   [[viewController navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```